# Ipad like text selection handles for html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my project to roll out the books that is for publishing company. The books are created as an Html pages with javascript turn effect. Within my application I have to use message event listeners to handle cross communication between pages and application. My requirement is to do style the text selection system as something similar to the following:

See that as an images:

but that doesn't answer, I want to handle pages both side with the selected text, then show a tool-tip with controls.

Any help would be highly appreciated!! :)

Comment: Ugh - messing with the way the user's OS does selections is going to be a huge amount of work, and take a long, long time until all quirks and bugs are ironed out. I would run away screaming from that job, and leave selecting to the user's OS. Just my 2 cents

Comment: Any specific browser support? Range selection like many things can be proprietary, **cough** IE

Comment: please mention which platform you are using for iPad using js,jquery. Is that phonegap or other

Comment: No, tis is a desktop application using (cough) ie. Unfortunately certain specs are out of my hand

Answer (score 3):

Try this jQuery plugin I created: http://codepen.io/mattsich/pen/MKvmxQ

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".full-text").selectBars('.full-text', 'ipsum', function(){
    $('.selected-text p').text($('.full-text').attr('data-selected'));
  });

});
```

Comment: Dude, this is awesome. Converting the code in plain js so that I could use it with React. Thanks a lot. +1

Comment: @rash.tay you didn't happen to publish this vanilla js version anywhere did you? It would be very helpful for a current project if so.

Comment: @ballmerspeak Unfortunately, I can't find it. I'll post it if I can find it.